# How affiliate work in opencart?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, affiliate

I registrated as a affiliate in opencart 2.0.3.1, I got a link in a special product, But when someone click on it, How can I see it in `panel admin`?

Comment: If someone add an order with an affiliate link, you can see affiliate name in order info.

Comment: Thanks, Can a affiliate create a link in a home page, not just in a specific product?? for example create link (my_domain.com) not just (my_domain.com/product1/pro1-1)

Comment: Nobody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this module 
[Home affiliate link](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=22557)

And it adds a field so affiliate can create link to home page :)